# On partitioning triangles and pentagons

Tags: discrete-geometry, dissection

1. Is there any triangle that can be cut into 5 mutually congruent pieces? If the answer is "yes" how does one characterize such triangles? What if we restrict the pieces to be convex?
2. Is there any convex pentagon that can be cut into 3 mutually congruent pieces?

Comment: Don't just paste the question and yeet off. Show us the work you tried, what you're confused on, ect. This isn't enough detail at all.

Comment: You may find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3922559/362967) interesting. It shows a dissection of an equilateral triangle into 5 congruent pieces, though the pieces are not connected subsets of the plane.

Comment: Thanks Jaap Scherphuis. The dissection you pointed at is certainly interesting. But I was looking for connected pieces although I didn't spell it out explicitly in the question.

Comment: A right triangle with legs in the ratio 2:1, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: drawing]

Worth a thousand words, they say.

Comment: thanks very much. i had indeed overlooked some basic possibilities while trying to dissect pentagons and hence asked the question. but then that is math!